# Call function with all instances of a struct

Tags: c++, function, struct

I want call a function with all struct objects.

I need a function that can loop through the struct-objects A_1, A_2 by calling only the struct STRUCT_A. The empty function 'reset_all_structs( ??? )' at the bottom of the code.

sample Code:

```
#include <iostream>


struct STRUCT_A {
    unsigned char number = 0;
    bool bool_1 = 0;
    bool bool_2 = 0;
} A_1, A_2; // Objects: maybe later A_3, ... , A_x

void print_to_terminal(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME);
void set_bool_1(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME);
void set_bool_2(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME);
void reset_one_struct(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME);
void reset_all_structs();

int main()
{

    set_bool_1(A_1);
    A_1.number = 111;
    set_bool_2(A_2);
    A_2.number = 222;
    std::cout << "A_1:\n";
    print_to_terminal(A_1);
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "A_2:\n";
    print_to_terminal(A_2);
    std::cout << "\n";

    reset_one_struct(A_1); // <-- Reset one struct works, my question ist how to reset all structs with the type STRUCT_A?
    std::cout << "A_1:\n";
    print_to_terminal(A_1);
    std::cout << "\n";

    set_bool_2(A_1);
    A_1.number = 234;
    std::cout << "A_1:\n";
    print_to_terminal(A_1);
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Here the question. ???

    // reset_all_structs( STRUCT_A );

    // I want to reset both A_1 and A_2 by calling the function reset_all_structs with all object of the struct "STRUCT_A" and loop through these. Is this possible
    // I don't want to call a function like reset_all_struct(A_1, A_2) because later I will add more objects of struct STRUCT_A.

    std::cout << "Reset A_1 and A_2\n";
    std::cout << "A_1:\n";
    print_to_terminal(A_1);
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "A_2:\n";
    print_to_terminal(A_2);
    std::cout << "\n";


    return 0;
}

void print_to_terminal(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME){
    std::cout << "Number: " << (int)STRUCT_NAME.number << "\n";
    std::cout << "bool_1: " << (int)STRUCT_NAME.bool_1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "bool_2: " << (int)STRUCT_NAME.bool_2 << "\n";
    return;
};

void set_bool_1(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME){
    STRUCT_NAME.bool_1 = 1;
    STRUCT_NAME.bool_2 = 0;
    return;
};

void set_bool_2(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME){
    STRUCT_NAME.bool_1 = 0;
    STRUCT_NAME.bool_2 = 1;
    return;
};

void reset_one_struct(STRUCT_A &STRUCT_NAME){
    STRUCT_NAME.number = 0;
    STRUCT_NAME.bool_1 = 0;
    STRUCT_NAME.bool_2 = 0;
    return;
};


void reset_all_structs( ??? ){
// loop through all structs
    return;
};
```

Comment: You are using a language that has facilities to handle this situation *if* your design makes use of those facilities.  Read about containers such as std::vector which can be used to manipulate one or more structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a local array and loop over it, like so:

```
void reset_all_structs()
{
    // This array can be created locally, and must capture by pointer 
    // arrays of references are illegal in C++.
    STRUCT_A * structs[] = { &A_1, &A_2 };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(structs); i++)
    {
      reset_one_struct(*structs[i]);
    }
}
```

Incidentally, you tagged your question C++, but this looks like C.  If you're new to C++, I'd recommend making all you functions that take a STRUCT_NAME into `methods` inside that struct.  At a minimum, rename the formal STRUCT_NAME parameters to something that doesn't appear to collide with the struct name itself, or a macro definition.  Finally, I'd suggest collecting your struct instances into an STL container, like `std::vector`, to make iteration and access in a loop simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `array` or even better `vector` of `structs` instead.

```
struct STRUCT_A {
    unsigned char number = 0;
    bool bool_1 = 0;
    bool bool_2 = 0;
};
typedef struct STRUCT_A Data;


void set_bool_1(Data& data_i) {
    data_i.bool_1 = 1;
}

void set_bool_2(Data& data_i) {
    data_i.bool_1 = 1;
}

void reset_one_struct(Data& data_i) {
    data_i.bool_1 = 0;
    data_i.bool_2 = 0;
    data_i.number = 0;
}
void reset_all_structs(std::vector<Data>& all_data) {
    for(int i = 0; i < all_data.size(); ++i)
        reset_one_struct(all_data[i]);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> my_data(2);
    set_bool_1(my_data[1]);
    my_data[1].number = 111;

    reset_one_struct(my_data[1]);
    reset_all_structs(my_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The language itself doesn't have a possibility to iterate through the same variables of the same types.

You can make some sort of registry of the structs and then iterate through this registry. Something like:

```
struct STRUCT_A;
std::vector<STRUCT_A*> struct_A_registry;

struct STRUCT_A {
   ...
   // constructor
   STRUCT_A() { struct_A_registry.push_back(this); }
   // destructor
   ~STRUCT_A() { 
      for (std::vector<STRUCT_A*>::iterator it = struct_A_registry.begin(); 
           it != struct_A_registry.end(); ++it) 
        if (*it == this) {
          struct_A_registry.erase(this);
          break;
        }
    }
};
```

Then your reset_all_structs will be just

```
void reset_all_structs() {
  for (std::vector<STRUCT_A*>::iterator it = struct_A_registry.begin(); 
       it != struct_A_registry.end(); ++it) 
    reset_one_struct(**it);
}
```

Or, if you are declaring all the STRUCT_A variables at the same line of the program, you can organize them into an array, it would be much simpler.